# if using rabbitmq mirror queue for HA, should define reply queue durable?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

if using rabbitmq mirror queue for HA with RPC pattern, should define reply queue durable?meanwhile, any special config to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the requirements of your application but, yes, it would make sense.

You have to use a named reply queue in that case, however; direct replyTo and/or a temporary reply queue won't work if need HA replies.